# Display the original question beneath the answer edit form

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, edits

Often when I edit one of my answers, it's because I want to better address the original question. The only problem is that I can't see the original question while I'm editing my answer!

I'd love to see the original question text beneath the "answer edit" form. This way I could scroll down slightly to read it if I wanted to, or just ignore it if not.

Current workaround is to click the 'return to answer' link and hope that you remember to launch it in a new tab/window, then tab back and forth.

Comment: Most important feature request on MSO if you ask me!

Comment: See also a workaround using Ctrl-clicking your browser's Back button in "What happened to the “Return to answer” link?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/what-happened-to-the-return-to-answer-link/27242#27242 -- which I've read doesn't work in Internet Explorer though.

Answer (score 39):

This bugs me too!

Alternatively, clicking "edit" could load the edit form right there on the page.  This would help in some cases where you want to copy/paste something from a comment or from another answer.

Comment: Upvote for the alternate idea- that's really how I think it should work.

Answer (score 6):

How about *above* the edit form?

Comment: Yes, above would be more useful, leave below for a preview of how the answer will look.

Answer (score 4):

#### For firefox users

[Greasemonkey script to show Question when editing Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12845/greasemonkey-script-to-show-question-when-editing-answers).

Comment: I actually use it, and find it quite helpful.  Except for the bug where it doesn't load the WMD editor tools and the preview.

Answer (score 2):

This would be great. Every time I edit an answer I have to open the question in another tab. I would prefer it above the form though.

Answer (score 2):

What's the status on this?

Now that even the [return to answer link is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/what-happened-to-the-return-to-answer-link), isn't this all the more relevant?

Comment: It looks like it's been implemented.

Answer (score -3):

Having 2 versions of the same question on a page would just make the page confusing tbh - I think that I prefer to see the original answer in a separate page myself anyway.