# When I'm composing the answer I want to see the question somewhere near

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, design

I see two possible solutions:

1. Put the answering form immediately below the question (in the collapsed state by default)
2. Put a copy of the question near the answering form.

Comment: This is a dupe, but I can't find it. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Got it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form

Comment: @John I made a GM script that shows the OQ on answer-editing pages...might you be thinking of that?

Comment: Nope, Jonathan, but thanks. I found it.

Comment: That question is a dupe of the second option.

Answer (score 3):

I often only have this problem when I'm editing my anwer after a comment or an edit to the question, else it's no problem to just scroll up to read it again.

Answer (score 2):

I would be against doubling the question near the answer form.

Often times I will just take care of this issue myself by opening up the question in a new tab or window so that I can have the answer pane available while still being able to see the question.

Answer (score 2):

Could there be anything wrong with placing the answer-form directly beneath the original-question, and simply not showing it until the user clicks "Answer," similar to when a user wants to answer their own question - a form isn't initially shown, until you indicate you wish to provide an answer.

That being said, I also think it would be wise to replicate the OQ on the answer-edit page.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking at this question and want the same thing: The greasemonkey script is there: [Display the original question beneath the answer edit form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form/12846#12846) (that's Jonathan Sampson's - thank you!)

Answer (score -1):

completing this, as "show answer when editing" is now functional.

[Display the original question beneath the answer edit form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form)

Comment: So we should answer the question quickly, then go back and edit it as soon as we post?