# Move answer textarea to top of all answers

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display the original question beneath the answer edit form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form)

I was answering a question today that had quite a few answers already (though I think my was better still). Because there were so many answers I had to scroll about 5 page ups and then back down about 3-4 times to copy little tidbits of code into the answer textarea that is at the very bottom of the stack.

I don't think it should be there by default but maybe once you start typeing in the box have it jump up, or the question body jump down.

Comment: Just hold the spacebar down :D

Comment: Take your pick: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/oh-wherefore-art-thou-question  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15644/dear-question-please-move-closer

Comment: 12 closure votes a day is nowhere near enough for Meta.

Comment: Come on, random! You love closing questions!

Comment: @Smithers Out of votes for the day. Burnt right through the dozen.

Comment: Jeff, random needs more votes! Best you make him a moderator for SU then he can clean the mess up here!

Comment: That would not be a good idea. On either count.

Comment: I love bad ideas :]

Answer (score 2):

I'm agin' it.

Putting the text area at the top would encourage people to answer without reading (or even scanning) the existing answers leading to too many duplicates.

**Workaround:** I open another tab to read the question in.

Comment: You are aging it?

Comment: I think he means the opposite of "fer it".

Answer (score 0):

Whilst [dmckee points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28834/move-answer-textarea-to-top-of-all-answers/28838#28838) that having the answer text box at the bottom encourages people to read all the existing answers on the way down, not everyone does. In my experience, the duplicate problem usually arises within the first five minutes of a question being asked when everyone knows the answer.

Quite often I'll answer questions whilst watching telly in the lounge using my Eee PC which has a tiny screen. Opening another window and/or scrolling up and down to read the question again can be extraordinarily annoying due to the small screen size.

Maybe the way to solve this is to keep the answer box where it is but have a button that when clicked moves it to just under the question, or it could be in a layer that could be dragged up the page. Just a thought.