# Have an option to view the question *below* the Answer Submission Form

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display the original question beneath the answer edit form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form)

In the Auld Auld days of Stackoverflow, we had a separate Answer this Question page.

Now, there is an answer form at the bottom of the question page. It would help enormously if I did not have to scroll up and down to look at the question each time I want to verify another minute detail.

I suggest that the question's text should appear below the answer form as well. For long questions, it can be conveniently placed in a scrollable div.

Comment: And can we have it on both sides as well?  And maybe as a translucent background on the answer form itself?

Comment: What I'll do if need be, I would usually open the question in a new window and flip it to my secondary display.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install a plugin like [Split Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4287), which allows the viewing of multiple pages (or different parts of the same page) together in one window?

Alternatively you could open the page in multiple tabs or windows.