# Display the original, unedited post on the post editing page

Tags: feature-request, edits

I edit people's posts occasionally on ServerFault when the grammar/punctuation/coherence goes below a threshold that my OCD can handle. However, on some of the thornier posts I would like to be able to compare my edits to the original text, especially when doing a final proof-reading of my edits.

At the moment, my only options are to either copy the original text into a text editor or copy a duplicate of the text into the editing field. From there I can compare my edits to the original text and make sure I'm preserving the original meaning as I attempt to untangle less than optimal communication.

This request is somewhat similar to this Meta post: "[Display the original question beneath the answer edit form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form)"

Comment: just open the edit link in a new window.  then you get a copy you can refer to.  no need for additional UI clutter: consider an uber-long post; you'd end up scrolling constantly to find the original text, tweak your copy, recheck the original, retweak, etc.  having another window open with the question gives you the whole question, less clutter on the edit, and access to commentary and answers should they be needed.

Comment: Good point. I'll give it a go.